# how can I call both functions with the button

Tags: regex, vue.js

I made a small app that filters a regular expressions (email addresses) and pastes them into the second textarea.
I understand that I need to use computed properties to filter it and then copy the content but still does not work.
Any suggestion, please?

```
<template>
 Paste Text: <br>
    <textarea name="output" cols="50" rows="12" v-model="rawText" placeholder="paste here"></textarea>
    <br>

    <button type="button" @click="filterReg(); extractEmails()">Get emails</button><br>
    <span class="counter"></span><br>
    Emails in text:<br>
    <textarea name="output" cols="50" rows="12" v-model="emails"></textarea>
    <div v-bind="regularExp">{{emailData}}</div>
</template>

<script>  
export default {

      data(){
        return {
            rawText: "hello email",
            emails:'',
   
            }   
        },

    computed: {
        filterReg(){
            let temp = this.rawText;
            let exp = /([A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi;
            let emailData = temp.match(exp);
            let holder=[];
            for (let x=0; x<emailData.length; x++){
                if(holder.indexOf(emailData[x])==-1){
                holder.push(emailData[x]);
                }
            }

           return emailData;
            
        }
    },

    methods:{
        extractEmails(){
        return this.emails = this.rawText;
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. filterReg is not a function and can't be called like filterReg(), so this depends on what exactly happens in extractEmails

Answer (score 0):

We cannot call two functions at once. But we can wrap both functions into a separate one and call that.

```html
<button type="button" @click="handleClick()">Get emails</button><br>
```

```js
{
  methods: {
   handleClick() {
     this.filterReg()
     this.extractEmails()
   },
   filterReg() {},
   extractEmails() {}
  }
}
```

P.S. we can only call vue methods, not computed properties.

Comment: thanks @pKiran but still does not work :(

Comment: Your question needs update, please format your js code and add it inside a codeblock. Paste the complete code which is relevant for the question.